# Odoo condiciones IF en modelos

Tags: python, odoo, openerp

Dentro de mi modelo citas tengo que comprobar que en un dia, un doctor a una hora solo pueda tener una cita disponible. Este es mi código y no se donde está el error.

```
class centromedico_citas(models.Model):
_name = 'centromedico.citas'

fconsulta = fields.Date(string="Fecha consulta", required=True)
hconsulta = fields.Float(string="Hora consulta", required=True)
cpaciente = fields.Many2one('centromedico.pacientes', string="Paciente",required=True, ondelete="cascade")
cdoctores = fields.Many2one('centromedico.medicos', string="Doctor/a", required=True, ondelete="cascade")
chistorial = fields.Many2one('centromedico.historialclinico', string="Historial", required=True, ondelete="cascade")

@api.constrains('fconsulta', 'hconsulta', 'cdoctores')
def _citaunica(self):
    for consultas in self:
        if consultas.fconsulta = centromedico.fconsulta and consultas.hconsulta = centromedico.hconsulta and consultas.cdoctores = centromedico.cdoctores: 
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(_("El doctor ya tiene una cita a esa hora ese día!")
```

Comment: Hola Pedro, en principio estás usando `=` (asignación) en el `if`, debería ser `==`.

Comment: Buenas, lo he cambiado a == y me sigue dando error, no me actualiza ni el modulo

Comment: ¿El error es el `exceptions.ValidationError` que lanzas si se cumple el `if` o es otro? Si es otro añade la traza completa del mismo a ver si podemos ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estas igualando al mismo objeto, ya que centromedico.consultas es igual consultas.fconsultas que es una referencia a self que es el objeto que estas llamando y a la variable fconsulta, el mismo caso en los otros dos.